# magento custom payment method form not showing

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, payment, checkout

I wrote a custom payment module. It seems to be working fine but I can't show the method form in the checkout process. I mean: I see my method, I can select it, but can't see the form.
I want to show a select box with a couple of options but no form is rendered.

**app\code\local\Neurona\Sistarbanc\Block\Form\sistarbanc.php**

```
class Neurona_Sistarbanc_Block_Form_Sistarbanc extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
  protected function _construct()
   {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('payment/form/sistarbanc.phtml');
   }
....
```

And the form in **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\payment\form\sistarbanc.phtml**

Any help will be appreciated!!

**EDIT**

[image: It works in a fresh magento install with default theme]
[image: It does NOT work in onestepcheckout]

**So, it seems to be working in the default ckeckout process but not in the onestepcheckout**

### **EDIT 2**

I found that in onestepheckout this is the way the payment method form is rendered:

```
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
  <dd id="container_payment_method_<?php echo $_code; ?>" class="payment-method" <?php if(!$this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code || !($hide_nonfree_methods && $_code == 'free')): ?> style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>>
<?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

So, for my method `$this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)` is `FALSE`. ¿why?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same issue and can't seem to get the form to render.

Answer (score 1):

Your template filename is `Sisterbanc.phtml`, but your block will try to load `sisterbanc.phtml` (uppercase "s" vs lowercase "s").

Comment: If logging is activated, this should also show up as missing template file in /var/log/system.log

Comment: Sorry but it was a typo in my post. Both filename and delcaration are lowercase. Nothing in the log

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need add this line in Model/Payment.php.

`protected $_formBlockType = "sistarbanc/form/sistarbanc"`

I don't know the reason why though. I compared with other payment module code, and got this.